# Haskell : Filtering a list of strings

Tags: haskell, filter

I have a list of Strings I want to filter through. My predicate is that the string should begin with an uppercase letter.

eg. when I run `onlyLowercase ["boy", "girl", "Hi"]`

it should give me a list of `["boy", "girl"]`

I can do it using pattern matching and guards, but I'm using the learnyouahaskell (http://learnyouahaskell.com) book and I came across the topic on higher-order functions. I read about the filter function and thought it could achieve what I want to do in far fewer lines of code.

**Using pattern Matching/Guards** (This works well and solves my problem)

```
onlyLowercase :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
onlyLowercase [] = []
onlyLowercase (x:xs) 
  | isLower (head x) = x : onlyLowercase xs  
  | otherwise = onlyLowercase xs
```

**Using the filter function**

```
onlyLowercase2 :: [String] -> [String]
onlyLowercase2 [] = []
onlyLowercase2 (x:xs) = filter isLower x : onlyLowercase2 xs
```

Unfortunately, when I run `onlyLowercase2 ["boy", "girl", "Hi"]`,
I get a list of `["boy", "girl", "i"]`.

I want to know if there's a way I can filter my list of strings using the first character in my string (without creating any auxiliary function that could check the String and return true if the first letter is lowercase).

I also tried using

```
 onlyLowercase2 (x:xs) = filter (isLower head x) : onlyLowercase2 xs
```

but that didn't even compile. Basically, I'm just trying to figure out how the filter function can be used on a list of lists. Thank you, in advance, for any assistance rendered.

Comment: Yes, but you should *not* filter on the element `x`, you filter over the list, and *in* the filter you take the head.

Comment: There is however here a case that will error: a list with an empty string.

Comment: So instead of taking (x:xs), I should just take xs as a parameter?

Comment: Do you *understand* what your `onlyLowercase2` does? How it works? Please do not just "trail-and-error" until a sensical function shows up.

Comment: I think I do, it takes in a list , then checks if the head (x) isLower, and if it's true, it adds it to the resulting list. I understand that's why it's when it comes to the string "Hi" in my example, the filter checks the entire string and adds the lowercase letters to the returning list. What I want to do however, is check only the firstcharacter of the string. I don't know the syntax to do that.

Comment: no. The filter should return `True` or `False`, if it returns `True` the *corresponding* value is added to the result list, if `False` it is *not* added.

Comment: I understand that part. I want the filter to check the first character only and not the whole string

Comment: well then *in* the filter function, you take the *first character* of that string. You do not first pre-process the elements that should be filtered.

Comment: That's what I tried to do by doing this (isLower head x), to only check the first character in the string, but that syntax doesn't work. So I'm just trying to know which syntax does

Comment: But you should *not* use `x` of the *outer* list. Define a lambda expression as filter function, so `filter (\x -> ...)`.

Comment: I haven't gotten to the topic on Lamba expressions in the book so let me learn how to use them then try again. :)

Comment: lamdas worked perfectly well. Thank you very much.

This was my final solution. `onlyLowercase2 = filter (\x -> ("" /= x) && (isLower $ head x))`

Comment: You may also go applicative style like `filter ((&&) <$> isLower . head <*> (/=""))` without a lambda.

Comment: This is way advanced for me haha. (only a couple of weeks into learning haskell), but I will read up on this so I can fully understand everything you've written. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's perfectly explained in http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors FYI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Willem Van Onsem's suggestion to use a lambda expression as a filter function, I read further and came up with this 2 line solution.

```
onlyLowercase2 :: [String] -> [String]
onlyLowercase2 = filter (\st-> ("" /= st) && (isLower $ head st))
```

Not sure if it's perfect, but at least it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Data.List` and `Data.Char`:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char

onlyLowerCase :: [String] -> [String]
onlyLowerCase = filter (all isLower)
```

I use the `all` function which checks that `all` elements of a list satisfy a predicate. In this case `all isLower` will return true if all letters in a `String` are lowercase. Then just `filter` the `Strings` that are all lowercase. The [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellpa2.html#haskellch16.html) has a good reference for [`List`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html#x28-22800020) and [`Char`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch16.html#x24-21100016.2) functions among other useful libraries.